# R FlexDashboard ggiraph chart not showing on second page of dashboard when using IE 11

Tags: javascript, r, knitr, flexdashboard, ggiraph

I have a multi-page R FlexdashBoard and I am trying to use ggiraph to create some interactive charts.  They show up fine on the first page of the dashboard, however on the second page the SVG graphics do not show up until I hit refresh then the charts on the first page disappear. Also the text in the SVG graphics seems to only display intermittently. I only have this error in Internet Explorer - everything works fine in Chrome.  The following code should recreate this error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated event a hint on which package or piece of java script to look at.

````
---
title: "Please Help Me!"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggiraph)
```

Works {data-orientation=rows}
=====================================  

Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r}
myIris <- iris
myIris$DataId<- row.names(iris)
g2 <- ggplot(data=myIris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, data_id=DataId)) + geom_point_interactive(fill = "green", alpha=.5)
ggiraph(code = print(g2), width_svg = 8, height_svg=4,
        hover_css="fill-opacity:1",flexdashboard =TRUE)

```

Column {data-width=350}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart B

```{r}

myIris <- iris
myIris$DataId<- row.names(iris)
g2 <- ggplot(data=myIris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, data_id=DataId)) + geom_point_interactive(fill = "green", alpha=.5)
ggiraph(code = print(g2), width_svg = 8, height_svg=4,
        hover_css="fill-opacity:1",flexdashboard =TRUE)
```

### Chart C

```{r}
myIris <- iris
myIris$DataId<- row.names(iris)
g2 <- ggplot(data=myIris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, data_id=DataId)) + geom_point_interactive(fill = "green", alpha=.5)
ggiraph(code = print(g2), width_svg = 8, height_svg=4,
        hover_css="fill-opacity:1",flexdashboard =TRUE)

```

Does Not Work {data-orientation=rows}
=====================================  

### Chart C

```{r}
myIris <- iris
myIris$DataId<- row.names(iris)
g2 <- ggplot(data=myIris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, data_id=DataId)) + geom_point_interactive(fill = "green", alpha=.5)
ggiraph(code = print(g2), width_svg = 8, height_svg=4,
        hover_css="fill-opacity:1",flexdashboard =TRUE)

```

### Chart D

```{r}
myIris <- iris
myIris$DataId<- row.names(iris)
g2 <- ggplot(data=myIris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, data_id=DataId)) + geom_point_interactive(fill = "green", alpha=.5)
ggiraph(code = print(g2), width_svg = 8, height_svg=4,
        hover_css="fill-opacity:1",flexdashboard =TRUE)

```
### Chart E

```{r}
myIris <- iris
myIris$DataId<- row.names(iris)
g2 <- ggplot(data=myIris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, data_id=DataId)) + geom_point_interactive(fill = "green", alpha=.5)
ggiraph(code = print(g2), width_svg = 8, height_svg=4,
        hover_css="fill-opacity:1",flexdashboard =TRUE)

```
````

Comment: I will have a look on that as soon as I can get an IE 11

Comment: Thanks David!  I am a big fan of ggiraph!  Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Any progress? Should I submit an issue on the flexdashboard github page?

Comment: David, I found a fix for this issue the the style.js in ggiraph.  I proposed a very minor change on github.

Comment: Sorry, didn't find time yet to look at that. soon... (I didn't see any PR, did you submit it?)