# R flexdashboard not rendered in IE 11

Tags: r, internet-explorer, flexdashboard

I have produced a series of dashboards using flexdashboard and have found that they work well in Chrome but do not render in IE 11.

I made a very simple dashboard for testing purposes and still all I get in IE is a blank page.  If I change the output from flexdashboard to html_document, it renders fine, so the problem appears to be with flexdashboard and not R Markdown.

Here's my simple dashboard:

````
---
title: "Flexdashboard - Internet Explorer test"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
---    
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
# Libraries
library(flexdashboard)
library(knitr)
library(ggplot2)
```
Iris
=========================================
Row
-------------------------------------
```{r}
ggplot(data=iris, aes(x=Petal.Length, y=Petal.Width, color=Species)) + geom_point()
```
````

And this is all I get in IE:
[flexdashboard IE fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygVNQ.png)

I have found no other reports of this exact issue, only a [similar problem using ggiraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43150055/r-flexdashboard-ggiraph-chart-not-showing-on-second-page-of-dashboard-when-using).

I had my coworker try to open the file using IE on her computer and results were the same.  I'd really like to get this working because some people in this org are only allowed IE.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907131/detecting-ie11-using-css-capability-feature-detection) will help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into the same issue when developing a dashboard for a client that could only use IE 11. The trick is to change the settings in the IE 11 browser. While the fix requires one manual step up front by the end user, once the setting is changed the end user should not experience issues loading the dashboard in IE 11.

1. Click on the settings gear in the top right corner of an IE 11 browser.
2. Select 'Compatability View settings' from the dropdown
3. Uncheck 'Display intranet sites in Compatibility View'
4. Close settings dialog box and open the dashboard

Comment: Thanks! This does the trick.  I had figured out it was something with our network settings, or the way IE is configured on our network, but had actually just told my boss to access in Chrome.  Thanks for responding to my old post.

Comment: Thanks for your contributions. I have this issue now. Unfortunately the Compatibility View setting doesn't solve it for me. Would anyone have any other ideas off the shelf, without need for a reproducible example from me? Many thanks